# Javascript .pop() and .sort() not working right in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to remove the last element in the array but it ends up putting the removed element back to the top of the list and some of the other elements are listed differently.

Same thing using the .sort() method. The output shows this sentence five times:
Tolstoy wrote War and Peace,Twain wrote Huckleberry Finn

```
var author_title = new Array(5)
author_title[0]="Tolstoy wrote War and Peace";
author_title[1]="Twain wrote Huckleberry Finn";
author_title[2]="Hardy wrote The Return of the Native";
author_title[3]="Dickens wrote A Christmas Carol";
author_title[4]="Uris wrote Exodus";

for(var count=0;count<author_title.length;count++) {
document.write(author_title.pop() + "<br>");
}

for(var count=0;count<author_title.length;count++) {
document.write(author_title.sort()+"<br>");
}
```

Comment: Don't iterate over arrays with `for...in` loops. `for...in` loops are for iterating over the properties of objects.

Comment: You shouldn't radically change your question. You've rendered any existing answers invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to alter your array then use pop, writing a variable that is equivalent to `array.length` outside of the `for` loop, then setting your variable to that declared variable. You have to remember that you are changing your array every time you .pop(), thus changing the `for-loop` in each iteration.  Also, the `<br />` is for HTML so you may have just forgotten your self-closing tag  on that

```
var length = array.length;
for( var i = 0; i > length; i++ ) {
     document.write( array.pop() + "\n")
}
```

Answer (score -2):

No part of this should work. `for..in` loops iterate over the *keys* for each properly, not the values. It's not meant for iterating over arrays. On my machine, it produces `0`,`1`,`2`,etc.

You're also attempting to `pop` elements while iterating over the array. `pop` modifies the array, so your iterator will be invalidated on each iteration.

What you want is a simple `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < author_title.length; ++i) {
  console.log(author_title[i]);
}
```

Comment: Oh okay thank you! I didn't know that. So in my loop I can write this author_title.pop() then do the document.write?

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. Why are you interested in using `pop` in the first place? If you're shrinking the array, you should just use `while (author_title[0]) { x = author_title.pop(); ... }`

Comment: I'm still new to Javascript. I'm just going by what the book I'm reading to do my coding lol

Comment: -1: `No part of this should work`. It absolutely **must** work in an ECMA-262 compliant implementation. Array indexes are just Object properties (Arrays are Objects), for..in loops over the enumerable properties absolutely reliably in every browser ever.

Comment: @RobG The point is it doesn't work as indicated by the question. He implies that the code as written prints out the *values* of each object property, when he's actually enumerating the property names (or array indices). As I said, it prints 0,1,2,etc, **not** *"shows this sentence five times: Tolstoy wrote War and Peace,Twain wrote Huckleberry Finn"*, which he claims it shows.